# Eliminar elementos duplicados en una dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dispongo de un dataframe con una columna tal que asi:

id             tlf

0        656565656,98989898,656565656,98989898

1        222222222,11111111,222222222,33333333

3        222222222,99999999

La idea es eliminar duplicados de la columna tlf y que me queden solo los unicos por cada id, he intentado con set y OrderedDict, sin exito, si alguien se le ocurre una idea!! Gracias

Comment: tambien intente drop_duplicates en una Lambda pero no he dado aun con la tecla....

Comment: Agrega lo que has intentado

Comment: Por cierto, existe el método  `drop_duplicates()`

Comment: si que he intentado pero no consigo los resultados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solución usando `pandas.Series.map`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'tlf':[
        '656565656,98989898,656565656,98989898',
        '222222222,11111111,222222222,33333333',
        '222222222,99999999'
    ]
})
df['tlf'] = df['tlf'].map(lambda a: ','.join(set(a.split(','))))
print(df)
```

Comment: Bueno y funciona!! gracias